# Is there a way to access the HTML of an In App Browser (Themeable Browser)

Tags: html, ionic-framework, browser

I am using the ionic framework and would like to be able to read from the HTML from the current webpage and then send the selection back to my application.

I have the Theme-able Browser Plugin setup and can use it like any other web browser.

I have tried looking at ways to include my own script with the .executeScript() function but no luck.

I have also tried to read data from custom buttons that I have inserted into the tool/nav bar but that gives me the HTML of my application.

TL;DR: (Basically want access to the DOM of the current webpage and have the user use native selection to read the document.getSelection() and send that text back to my application.)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the forums on Ionic I found the solution:

```
browser.executeScript({code:'window.getSelection().toString();'}).then((selection)=>{
packet.text = selection[0];});
```

This allows me to get the selection.